# ggplot: plot grid with double y label, colored cells and condition

Tags: r, ggplot2

For a data frame similar to the one below, I want to make a grid with product and batch on the y-axis, year on the x-axis and filled cells (color = red) where outcome >= 1. Cells with outcome < 1 should remain white.
Additionally I would like to have the value from the column Outcome displayed in the red coloured cell (but not the white cells).

```
df <- data.frame(product = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"),
                 batch = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2),
                 year = c(2018,2018,2019,2019,2018,2018,2019,2019),
                 outcome = c(.52,.13,.63,.27,1.5,.15,.19,2.1))
```

Here is what I have so far, but I can't find a way to add product to the y-axis:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = as.factor(year), y = as.factor(batch), fill = outcome >= 1))+
  geom_tile(colour = 'black')+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('FALSE' = 'white', 'TRUE' = 'red')) +
  theme_bw()
```

Desired output:

[image: desired plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new variable :

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(product = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"),
                 batch = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2),
                 year = c(2018,2018,2019,2019,2018,2018,2019,2019),
                 outcome = c(.52,.13,.63,.27,1.5,.15,.19,2.1))


df %>% 
  mutate(pb = paste(product, batch, sep = " / ")) %>% 
  ggplot( aes(x = as.factor(year), y = fct_rev(pb), fill = outcome >= 1))+
    geom_tile(colour = 'black') +
    geom_text(aes(label = if_else(outcome >= 1, outcome, NA_real_))) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c('FALSE' = 'white', 'TRUE' = 'red')) +
    labs(x = "Year",
         y = "Product / batch") +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0))
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I think that should work

Comment: rotating the y axis label is maybe better (updated answer)